# How do I do to show only days with an event in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar plugin connected to Google Calendar and it shows all days, including days that don't have an event. I need it to show just days with an event. Is it possible?

Comment: For your deleted post in sfse... you need to make your method async

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a full answer since I am still chewing on this myself, but you might has well know what I've done. I work in a custom basic Day view called vertWeek, which looks like an agenda view. In dayRender, I have tried looping (.each) over fc-row and using freight trains of .has and .hasClass to try to hunt down those rows that have a td cell with .fc-container-event. The existence of this should be enough but no matter what I try I can't isolate a specific day-row. All rows get a green border or in the negative they get a red border.

I know my each works coz if I use .html on the index each row prints out its index number neatly. I don't have code handy, am away and tired, but go look for a post about squishing box calendar rows without events in them to get a gist of my efforts.

Hope this helps.